# AMD Radeon R5 M335 GPU not detected correctly?

Tags: release-freya, graphic-drivers, hardware, drivers, graphics

I have a brand new Dell Inspiron 15 (5559) laptop with an **Intel Skylake i7-6500U CPU** and an **AMD Radeon R5 M335** graphics card.

I'm not sure though if freya has correctly detected the AMD Radeon card. When I run

lspci -nnk | grep -i VGA -A2

the only output there is mentions the integrated Intel Skylake graphics:

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics [8086:1916] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:06b2]
    Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo

However, in the "additional drivers" tab in the update preferences panel, the system tells me there is an AMD Sun XT Radeon HD 8600M graphics card running on the open source Xorg driver. There is also the option to select the propriety fglrx driver.

So how do I know if freya has correctly detected the Radeon R5 M335 card? Does my card maybe have the same chipset as the Radeon HD 8600M that is mentioned in the additional drivers settings?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem is the open source xorg drivers that are activated by default. You have to use the proprietary drivers (called fglrx) instead, which are included in the repositories. You can choose between fglrx and the open source xorg drivers in the additional drivers tab of the update settings. Once activated, the Radeon R5 M335 is detected and apparently works fine.